# How To Query IdeaComments Object On Created Date

Tags: apex, ideas

I have a requirement where i need to create a email digest for the IdeaComments object. Send an email to an Idea owner every week listing the IdeaComments for his Idea in the last 1 week. However IdeaComments records cannot be filtered based on the CreatedDate field. I get the below error when I try to query on CreatedDate:

Implementation restriction. When querying the Idea Comment object, you must filter using the following syntax: CommunityId = [single ID], Id = [single ID], IdeaId = [single ID], Id IN [list of IDs], or IdeaId IN [list of IDs].

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as per the design and all the parameters mentioned should be passed in where clause.

Reference: 
http://salesforcesandbox.googlecode.com/svn/SandboxNEW/src/classes/IdeaProfileController.cls

Hope this helps!